# Why does setting CLICOLOR=1 not turn on colors for "ls"?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, color

If I do `ls -G`, I *do* get the colors. From what I understood from the man pages, if I go into `~/.bash_profile` and add `export CLICOLOR=1` I would then get colors by doing just `ls`, as "This option is equivalent to defining CLICOLOR in the environment."

Am I understanding this wrong? Because it's not working for me on Yosemite 10.10.5 in bash with homebrew coreutils(not sure how much of that is relevant). I tried adding this in `~./bashrc` but same thing. I could always just alias my ls to ls -G, but I want to do this the "right" way. I also tried adding `export LSCOLORS=...` but it didn't help either. Like I said I *do* get colors with `-G`, but I'd like to get them by default by just typing `ls` and not having to set an alias for it, unless my understanding of how this works is wrong.

Comment: If you set the variable manually in your active shell, does ls have colors? It's possible your bash_profile is either not being sourced, or being overwritten for some reason

Comment: What happens if you run `CLICOLOR=1 \ls ~` (the `\` is intentional)?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125060/terminal-not-displaying-colors-for-directory-listings?rq=1 as well

Comment: You likely didn't source the file. Run `. ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 2):

A few issues.

Homebrew coreutils ls is not the OSX/freebsd ls. Coreutils is GNU, and that ls uses --colors instead of -G. -G in gnu ls means do not show groups. It does not use CLICOLOR either. There is no environmental variable to set colors for gnu ls.

OSX's ls uses -G as a command line option, in the same way that exporting CLICOLOR would as an environmental variable.

So you are using the wrong variable for the wrong command.