# iTerm not showing colors for directories/folders

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm, color

I have tried solutions in various places (including [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125060/terminal-not-displaying-colors-for-directory-listings) but there are still no color in my iTerm.

I have these lines in my `.bash_profile`:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=cxfxdxdxhxegedabagacad
```

And if I do `ls`, it gives me everything in the same color:

[image]

any help? Thanks!

BTW, I am using https://github.com/nightsense/vimspectr for the shell but even I removed it, the terminal still has no color.

Comment: what does `env | grep COLOR` show?

Comment: @thrig it shows:```CLICOLOR=1
COLORFGBG=7;0
COLORTERM=truecolor```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know why. I was using [`nightsense-carbonzied`](https://github.com/nightsense/carbonized) for my shell as well, besides Vim. When I removed it, its fine.

I used [`vimspectr`](https://github.com/nightsense/vimspectr) previously and even if I stopped that, that won't come back to normal and I do not know why...