# How to get colors from 'ls' command on macOS

Tags: bash

I have tried both

```
 ls --color=auto
```

and

```
 ls -G
```

The first gives `ls: illegal option -- -`  and the second simply has no effect.  So then what is the way to get color for ls on macOS?  I am using the default *bash* on *catalina*

I am using the standard *Terminal.app*

```
$echo $TERM  
vt100
```

Comment: `-G` should do it (check `man ls` for details); if it doesn't, something else is blocking it. What Terminal program are you using, and what does `echo "$TERM"` print?

Comment: standard `Terminal.app` .  `$echo $TERM  vt100`

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/125076/37797

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to open the Preferences window in Terminal.app. Turn to the Profiles tab, and then the Advanced tab. You'll see that it says "Declare terminal as", which you would have set to `vt100`. Change this to `xterm-256color`.

Now you can run `ls -G` to see a coloured `ls` output.